# What is Authority of Pack URI in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

I feel extremely dumb but I do not understand WPF Pack URI.

I am reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx and am having difficulty understanding what authority is.

I understand that URI has to be in the format of `pack://<authority><path>`

And they specifically defined authority.

> The authority specifies the type of package that a part is contained by

OK someone please help me what this statement means.

I know the image below this statement has authority pointing at package but I do not quite understand it still.

What is authority?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can describe this better than what the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx) you provided does.  Most of the time, you will use `application:`, and it is more rare to use `siteoforigin:`.  The WPF Samples use both of these.  Maybe they will help you learn the subtle differences.

[StickyNotesDemo](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Sample%20Applications/StickyNotesDemo/GenerateImageResources.cs)

Authority: siteoforigin:///.

Path: The name of the site of origin file, including its path relative to the location from which the executable assembly was launched.

[AnimationExamples](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Animation/AnimationExamples/SampleViewer.cs)

Authority: application:///.

Path: The name of the content file, including its path relative to the file system location of the application's main executable assembly.